# What do the TalkBack reading controls do?

Tags: accessibility, talk-back

I am trying to use TalkBack on a Realme 6 Android 11 phone.

When I activate TalkBack by pressing the volume up and volume down keys simultaneously, I can then iterate through the following entries by swiping up then down to move forward, or down then up to move backwards:

- Spoken language
- Speech rate
- Windows
- Links
- Controls
- Headings
- Paragraphs
- Words
- Characters

However, I don't understand what these entries are. What are they, what do they do, or how do I use them, using TalkBack?

Thank you for your replies.

Answer (score 0):

After selecting the desired entry by swiping up then down to move forward, or down then up to move backwards, you can select subentries (for instance, for spoken language), by swiping your finger up (to go back), or swiping your finger down (to move forward). In the case of spoken language selection, this will select the language used to read the text. You can then tap on the screen to read the text under the finger, with the language in the selected voice, or move the finger forward or backwards to read the previous or the next entry.

Other settings in the swipe up/swipe down menu can be activated similarly.